# side effect of caption package with custom counter

Tags: numbering, captions

--- update ---

Any comments, is this a bug in the `caption` package or do have have to protect `\refstepcounter` somehow?

--- \update ---

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{caption}

\newcounter{mycounter} % make a counter
\setcounter{mycounter}{0} % init the counter

\NewDocumentCommand \mymark {} {%
\refstepcounter{mycounter}%
\textsuperscript{\themycounter}}

\begin{document}
%
one\mymark

\begin{figure}
\caption{two\mymark}
\label{lab:1}
\end{figure}%

three\mymark

\end{document}
```

without caption package it produces

[image: no_caption]

but if I add the package

[image: with_caption]

Why is the numbering incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `caption` package typesets the caption twice.

You can add some test to see whether you're in a caption and, in that case, do the stepping only the first time. I use `\caption@beginhook` to inject the necessary code when typesetting the caption.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcounter{mycounter} % make a counter

\NewDocumentCommand\mymark{}{%
  \ifandyincaption
    \ifandysteppedcounter
    \else
      \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
      \global\andysteppedcountertrue
    \fi
  \else
    \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  \fi
  \textsuperscript{\themycounter}%
}
\newif\ifandyincaption
\newif\ifandysteppedcounter

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \g@addto@macro\caption@beginhook{%
    \andyincaptiontrue
    \global\andysteppedcounterfalse
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

one\mymark

\begin{figure}
\caption{two\mymark}
\label{lab:1}
\end{figure}

three\mymark (\ref{lab:1})

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason, why the `caption` package typesets twice?

Comment: @Andy It wants to check whether the caption fits on one line and uses a slightly different method than standard LaTeX.